Spring Boot stuck at "HikariPool-1 Starting..." suddenly after months of working properly for DB2 connection
I have two Spring Boot applications which connect to two dbs. The first is a DB2 on cloud using the "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" driver. The second uses other driver. For more than a year I've been running this apps locally with no issues. I stopped working at these apps for some weeks now and worked in another app that uses the "com.ibm.db2.db2jcc4.DB2Driver" and is not a maven app. I've been trying to run my old application with no changes in configs and now they both get stuck on the first database connection until they timeout and move to the other, which connects with no issues.
Here the logs:
2024-07-28 01:26:07.862 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : Driver class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver found in Thread context class loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@e42661c8
2024-07-28 01:26:07.908  INFO 53348 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-07-28 01:26:07.948  INFO 53348 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.15.Final
2024-07-28 01:26:08.083  INFO 53348 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2024-07-28 01:26:08.225 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : HikariPool-1 - configuration:
2024-07-28 01:26:08.228 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : allowPoolSuspension................................false
2024-07-28 01:26:08.228 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : autoCommit................................true
2024-07-28 01:26:08.228 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : catalog................................none
2024-07-28 01:26:08.228 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionInitSql................................none
2024-07-28 01:26:08.228 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionTestQuery................................none
2024-07-28 01:26:08.229 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionTimeout................................30000
2024-07-28 01:26:08.229 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSource................................none
2024-07-28 01:26:08.229 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceClassName................................none
2024-07-28 01:26:08.229 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceJNDI................................none
2024-07-28 01:26:08.229 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceProperties................................{password=<masked>}
2024-07-28 01:26:08.229 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : driverClassName................................"com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
2024-07-28 01:26:08.229 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : exceptionOverrideClassName................................none
2024-07-28 01:26:08.230 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : healthCheckProperties................................{}
2024-07-28 01:26:08.230 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : healthCheckRegistry................................none
2024-07-28 01:26:08.230 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : idleTimeout................................600000
2024-07-28 01:26:08.230 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : initializationFailTimeout................................1
2024-07-28 01:26:08.230 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : isolateInternalQueries................................false
2024-07-28 01:26:08.230 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : jdbcUrl................................jdbc:db2://2fc27203-0678-410a-8a5d-ae2eb14c932d.c3n41cmd0nqnrk39u98g.private.databases.appdomain.cloud:32614/bludb:sslConnection=true;sslCertLocation=/Users/kalioofarril/Documents/APCC/DigiCertGlobalRootCA_db2apccdev2_public.crt;
2024-07-28 01:26:08.230 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : keepaliveTime................................0
2024-07-28 01:26:08.231 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : leakDetectionThreshold................................0
2024-07-28 01:26:08.231 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : maxLifetime................................1800000
2024-07-28 01:26:08.231 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : maximumPoolSize................................10
2024-07-28 01:26:08.231 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : metricRegistry................................none
2024-07-28 01:26:08.231 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : metricsTrackerFactory................................none
2024-07-28 01:26:08.231 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : minimumIdle................................10
2024-07-28 01:26:08.231 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : password................................<masked>
2024-07-28 01:26:08.232 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : poolName................................"HikariPool-1"
2024-07-28 01:26:08.232 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : readOnly................................false
2024-07-28 01:26:08.232 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : registerMbeans................................false
2024-07-28 01:26:08.232 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : scheduledExecutor................................none
2024-07-28 01:26:08.232 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : schema................................none
2024-07-28 01:26:08.232 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : threadFactory................................internal
2024-07-28 01:26:08.232 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : transactionIsolation................................default
2024-07-28 01:26:08.232 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : username................................"71ccdba8"
2024-07-28 01:26:08.232 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : validationTimeout................................5000
2024-07-28 01:26:08.232  INFO 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-07-28 01:28:08.682 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to create/setup connection: [jcc][t4][2043][11550][4.33.31] Exception java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Error opening socket to server /166.9.59.42 on port 32,614 with message: connect timed out. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
2024-07-28 01:28:08.688 DEBUG 53348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Cannot acquire connection from data source

java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: [jcc][t4][2043][11550][4.33.31] Exception     java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Error opening socket to server /166.9.59.42 on port 32,614 with message: connect timed out. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001

The same code and environment variables work fine on the cloud server and on my colleagues pc. My only hint is a question is which someone trying to connect via a db GUI is using the jcc4 driver and his solution was changing the driver using. I'm thinking that the other application somehow made the jcc4 driver run in my computer on some port which might be the same as the jcc driver I want to use and thus is interfering with this db connection.
This is the only explanation I can think of but I am no driver expert so maybe I'm completely off.
My application.properties file contains:
apcc.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
apcc.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://${APCC_DB_URL}:${APCC_DB_PORT}/${APCC_DB_NAME}:sslConnection=true;sslCertLocation=${APCC_DB_CERT_PATH};
apcc.datasource.username=${APCC_DB_USER}
apcc.datasource.password=${APCC_DB_PASSWORD}

I have tried changing dbs from dev to qa on the URL, taking working urls from cloud applications. I hace tried changing java versions and erasing and creating new builds.

Is port number 32614 blocked by a firewall on your workstation?  Can any other  jdbc app connect to the same database from your workstation ? If NONE can connect then either the port is blocked or the cloud database is not available.  IF at least one can connect, then your jdbc driver as used by spring boot needs to be updated. Your question should contain the exact jdbc driver version details (as reported by the driver itself).

Hello, the port 32614 is not at use. No apps I have tried (3) can connect to any of this db2 db using the same driver. Other dbs with other divers seem to not have the issue. I've tried changing the driver versions, more recently the com.ibm.db2:jcc:11.5.8.0 but all the version I tried have the same behavior.

From the log file in your question, the hikari jdbcurl is jdbc:db2://2fc27203-0678-410a-8a5d-ae2eb14c932d.c3n41cmd0nqnrk39u98g.private.databases.appdomain.cloud:32614/bludb:sslConnection=true;sslCertLocation=/Users/kalioofarril/Documents/APCC/DigiCertGlobalRootCA_db2apccdev2_public.crt; It has port 32614, but your comment says "is not at use". Evidence suggests you are mistaken. Fix your configuration, use the right port and ensure that port is open in all software and hardware firewalls. Trivial problem to solve.

Check the firewall between your application and the DB. Since you kept the port number constant, it may be the case that the port is blocked by your firewall and is not open for accepting connection requests.
Alternatively, consider changing the port number if possible, and then it should work.
The above solution assumes that the DB server is healthy.
